# Create a folder alias in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I know that I can create variable that represents a folder path in my profile.  For example,

```
$here = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
```

Is there an easy way to create an alias to a directory in PowerShell?

Create an alias

```
PS> Create-FolderAlias -name $foo -path "C:\Program Files"
```

Create an alias based on another alias

```
PS> Create-FolderAlias -name $bar -path $foo + "\Microsoft"
```

Use alias as expected

```
PS> cd $foo
```

It would be nice if these aliases would be persisted between sessions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can turn a folder into a new powershell drive with [New-PSDrive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx)

```
New-PSDrive foo filesystem 'C:\Program Files'
New-PSDrive bar filesystem 'foo:\Microsoft'
cd foo:
```

To persist between sessions you could add them to your profile script ($profile).

But of course you can also cd to a folder from a variable

```
$foo = 'C:\Program Files'
$bar = Join-Path $foo 'Microsoft'
cd $foo
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternative solution is to write a function that `cd`'s to that directory. For me, this yields the least amount of typing to get where I want. For instance, I put the following function in my `profile.ps1`:

```
# quickly cd to folder
function <short name> {
    cd <path to directory>
}
```

Then, in Powershell:

```
PS> <short name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just elaborate on @en casa's response and add a concrete example.

1. Open powershell's equivalent of .bash_profile:
   `notepad $profile`
2. Add aliases

```
function code { cd C:\Users\john\code }
function work { cd C:\Users\john\work }
function stuff { cd C:\Users\john\stuff }
```

3. Restart PS and type `PS> code` to get to the code folder.