# Create an alias to quickly navigate to a folder

Tags: powershell

I want to include *something* in my PowerShell profile loading script that makes it very easy for me to navigate across different folders (different code repositories).

I've seen examples that uses [New-PSDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598373/2874896) but I thought aliases is a smoother way of doing it. Aliases just *feels* better.

I'm looking for something like this:

(In profile.ps1)

```
New-Item alias:foo -value c:\repos\my\code\here
```

... Later on in the in the powershell console ...:

`cd $foo`

And voila! I'm now standing in the `c:\repos\my\code\here` directory.

What's the right approach?

**EDIT:** I've marked Martins answer as accecpted as its very straight to the point, however I recommend you also read Matt's answer, it has some great points.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would create a `$repos` hashtable containing all your repositories:

```
$repos = @{
    angular = 'c:\repos\my\angular\here'
    typescript = 'c:\repos\my\typescript\here'
    csharp = 'c:\repos\my\csharp\here'
}
```

Put this in your `$profile` and you can change the directories like this:

```
cd $repos.angular
```

And even use **tab-completion**!

Comment: Seems cool but unfortunately it doesn't work, getting `Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal`

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Can you post the code you put in your profile?

Comment: Yep I did something wrong, had invalid syntax in the key name, `angular-code` for example.

Comment: you can still do this if you surround the names in quotes. However I would try to avoid it

Answer (score 5):

```
$var = 'c:\repos\my\code\here'
cd $var
```

Comment: You must have quotation marks around `c:\repos\my\code\here` but yea apart from that it seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the right approach?

There is no right or wrong approach. Aliases are useful but they are only good for calling other cmdlets via another name. You cannot changes settings or add parameters etc.

Something else to consider would be to use `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` inside custom functions in your profile! That way you can change to where you need to be and go back to where you were when you are done.

```
function myfolder{
    Push-Location c:\temp
}

function imdone{
    Pop-Location
}
```

Calling `myfolder` with change directory to `c:\temp`. Do your stuff... even change to other directories. `imdone` would take you back to where you were *before* you called `myfolder`. Adding more directories to flip around to can complicate this but you can name stacks to return to. Push and Pop are robust enough for this.

This can easily be incorporated with [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41191258/3829407) for a more robust profile where it is easier to make centralized changes.

Even if you don't the features of `Push-Location` and `Pop-Location` you can just use `cd "path"` inside functions and name them as you see fit.

```
function tmp{cd "c:\temp"}
```

Just be careful that you don't use names that might already be taken. You could end up with a [precedence issue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_precedence)

Comment: Encapsulating all this into functions is interesting. Good tips.

Answer (score 0):

Used the solutions provided by  [Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191209/create-an-alias-to-quickly-navigate-to-a-folder/41191258#41191258) and [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191209/create-an-alias-to-quickly-navigate-to-a-folder/41191209#41191597)
and
created the below solution  to easily navigate to my repos and back to original location.

```
 $repos = @{
 play= 'H:\0_PlayGround\play'
 training= 'H:\0_PlayGround\training-tracker'
 }

 function goTo(){
    param (
               [parameter (Mandatory=$true, position=0, ParameterSetName='path')]
               [string ]$path
    )
   Push-Location ($path)
  }

function goBack{
 Pop-Location
 }
```

**Invoke it using :**

```
goto $repos.play
goback
```